# Tor doesn't stop after calling "service stop"

Tags: startup

I suppose that tor must start on startup, right? However, I usually need to restart it as if it's slow or not working at start. So, I use `sudo service tor stop`, but it won't stop immediately or consistently. When I run `tor` in command line again, it says:

```
Oct 12 17:46:29.744 [notice] Tor 0.3.5.8 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1b, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.3.8.
Oct 12 17:46:29.744 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Oct 12 17:46:29.744 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Oct 12 17:46:29.746 [notice] Based on detected system memory, MaxMemInQueues is set to 5769 MB. You can override this by setting MaxMemInQueues by hand.
Oct 12 17:46:29.747 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Oct 12 17:46:29.747 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Oct 12 17:46:29.747 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Oct 12 17:46:29.747 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9051: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
```

Sometimes, I must start and stop it for several times until to get a fresh run.

Comment: Port 9050 is the standalone Tor service.
Port 9051 is the service that is with the Tor Browser.

Are you running both?

Comment: I don't have Tor Browser

Comment: I use 9050 for socks and torsocks before command line, I also use privoxy for http, I am really confused what is the best practice for tor

Comment: Best practice is using the Tor Browser but that's only available on Intel based Windows/Mac/Linux so if you are using something different, it is usually best to used Firefox with a socks 5 proxy with DNS. I don't know what privoxy is so I can't tell you if is helps or hinders your anonymity.

Comment: I tried to install tor browser from software center, but it says it can't download it, it says are you sure your tor running...

Comment: Moreover, it says can't bind for both 9050 and sometimes 9051, the matter is that `service stop` doesn't stop it.

Comment: install lsof. "sudo lsof -i :9050" and "sudo lsof -i :9051". This will tell you specifically what is using both of those ports. After you stop the Tor service, run these commands to see if something is still keeping the port open.

Comment: is it tor or Tor?! what should I use in the stop command

Comment: The service name is tor. "service stop tor" should be fine.

Comment: You're going to need to provide enough details to reproduce the problem in order to have the best chance of getting help.  What OS, hardware, how did you install Tor, how is it configured, what other software have you installed, etc etc etc.